# console source tab shows me a typo in the code, but in the file there is no typo

Tags: javascript, console, google-chrome-devtools

So I keep getting `script.js:64 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token` error, even tho there is nothing on the line 64 in my code, but in the source tab in chrome, in my javascript file I see typo on that line
[image]

What is the problem here? My code:

```
function Question (theQuestion, theChoices, theCorrectAnswer) {
  this.question = theQuestion;
  this.choices = theChoices;
  this.correctAnswer = theCorrectAnswer;
  this.UserAnswer = "";
  var newDate = new Date();
  QUIZ_CREATED_DATE = newDate.toLocaleDateString();
  this.getQuizDate = function () {
        return QUIZ_CREATED_DATE;
    };
  console.log("Quiz Created On: " + this.getQuizDate());
}

Question.prototype.getCorrectAnswer = function () {
  return this.correctAnswer;
}

Question.prototype.getUserAnswer = function () {
  return this.UserAnswer;
}

Question.prototype.displayQuestion = function () {
  var questionToDisplay = "<div class='question'>" + this.question + "</div><ul>";
  choiceCounter = 0;

  this.choices.forEach(function (eachChoice) {
  questionToDisplay += '<li><input type="radio" name="choice" value="' + choiceCounter + '">' + eachChoice + '</li>';
    choiceCounter++;
  });
  questionToDisplay += "</ul>";
  console.log (questionToDisplay);
}

function MultipleChoiceQuestion (theQuestion, theChoices, theCorrectAnswer) {
  Question.call(this, theQuestion, theChoices, theCorrectAnswer);
  inheritPrototype(MultipleChoiceQuestion, Question);
}
​

allQuestions.forEach(function (eachQuestion)  {
    eachQuestion.displayQuestion();
});

clickBtn();
```

I tried to refresh cache, but doesn't help.

Comment: There may be some invisible characters after the `MultipleChoiceQuestion` function. Remove `} <newlines> allQuestions`, and ___manually___ type out that part again.

Comment: What do you mean invisible? How is that possible if there is nothing. How can I check for invisible characters?

Comment: There are characters that take no space, and as such, aren't visible in the editor. (Depending on the editor) since Chrome says there's something funny going on after the `MultipleChoiceQuestion` function, delete the end of that function up to the start of that `forEach`, then type it out again. That way, you can make sure there's nothing weird going on on those lines.